# Existe-t-il un préfixe opposé à « méta- » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, préfixes, grec

Le sens du préfixe, *à un niveau supérieur* (pour simplifier), est tout-à-fait de nature à être inversé, c'est-à-dire exprimant *à un niveau inférieur*. Pour préciser suite au commentaire de Najib, il ne s'agit effectivement pas de niveau supérieur au sens spatial mais au sens logique. Il faudrait peut-être dire *d'un niveau englobant celui du contexte courant*.

La locution « *au delà [de]* » a bien pour opposé correspondant « *en deçà [de]* », exactement dans le sens que je cherche.

Mais y a-t-il des mots qui incorporent cette idée sous forme de préfixe ? Si oui, avez-vous des exemples de couples d'opposés ?

Comment: Peut-être intra- ?

Comment: Je ne pense pas que traduire "méta-" par "de niveau supérieur" soit vraiment correct (en fait ça ne marche pour presque aucun mot qui commence par "méta-"). Vu qu'en grec "méta-" signifie "après, au-delà", le préfixe "pré-" pourrait marcher (même si c'est du latin). Ou bien "pro-", qui est grec mais c'est plus ambigu je trouve. "métaphysique"/"préphysique" ? Je ne sais pas.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Non, *pre-* s'opposerait plutôt à *post-*. Mais *au-delà* n'est pas *après*, son sens n'est ni temporel ni spatial. En ce qui concerne *proto-*, c'était ma première intuition, mais ce n'est que voisin, le préfixe véhiculerait plutôt l'idée de *premier* au sens originel ou primitif.

Comment: @Bregalad *intra* ne s'oppose-t-il pas plutôt à *extra* ?

Comment: "post-" est latin, "méta-" est grec, les deux ont le même sens dans leurs langues respectives ("après, au-delà"). Je n'ai pas suggéré "proto-", j'ai suggéré "pro-". Et si je suis d'accord que "au-delà" et "après" n'ont pas le même sens, "méta-" peut vouloir dire les deux (eg. "métastase").

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Ton analyse est en tous cas intéressante, ça aurait mérité une réponse à part entière plutôt qu'un commentaire, je pense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *En français, méta- assume plusieurs sens dans la formation de noms
>   savants (en biologie, médecine, physique, chimie, philosophie et
>   sciences humaines): il exprime la postérité temporelle, la succession,
>   ce qui est à la fin (par opposition aux mots préfixés en pro-, proto-,
>   méso-), un stade quelconque dans une suite, une transcendance (en
>   philosophie), un statut logique englobant un changement, le résultat
>   d'un processus, une proximité, une ressemblance (surtout en chimie et
>   minéralogie).*
>
> [ *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*, sous la direction
>   de A. Rey, Ed. le Robert - à « méta- » ]

Il faut donc identifier le sens pour un mot particulier et chercher l'opposé approprié; il est [difficile](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/12162) de déterminer un générique à cette fin. En effet, l'absence d'aspect spatial a proprement parler affaiblit la comparaison avec la locution présentée (« au delà [de] »). On peut jeter un coup d'oeil à un préfixe comme [méso-](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/meso) ( « qui est situé au milieu » ); on retrouve bien des termes, comme par exemple *mésotherme* (adj.) c'est-à-dire qui *s’accommode d'une chaleur moyenne* (TLFi).

Comment: (+1) pour la polysémie du préfixe, que j'avais peut-être enfermé à tort dans son sens philosophique ou logique. En lisant ta réponse je me dis en effet que je recherche peut-être à tort un terme générique alors que les opposés sont multiples et dépendent du contexte. A approfondir.

Answer (score 4):

Le préfixe *proto-*, déjà mentionné dans la citation de [la réponse d'Amphiteóth](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/13437/79), a le sens de « premier » et vient aussi du grec ancien, par opposition à ce qui vient « après ». C'est probablement la réponse canonique à cette question, bien que le nombre de mots référencés dans les dictionnaires qui utilisent ces deux préfixes soient peu nombreux et ne permettent pas de mettre cette opposition très clairement en évidence.

On peut tout de même noter l'opposition temporelle lors d'une évolution:

- [protozoaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/protozoaire), [métazoaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/m%C3%A9tazoaire).

Et l'opposition causale dans un processus de formation:

- [protoplasme](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/protoplasme), [métaplasme](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/m%C3%A9taplasme).

Comment: Ca confirme ma première intuition, que j'avais rejetée en lisant trop vite la définition du préfixe proto-. "Premier" peut effectivement avoir ce sens, j'étais bêtement resté sur le plan temporel. Merci également pour ces exemples opposés qui me manquaient cruellement. Je laisse encore un jour de réflexion par principe mais je pense que je vais accepter cette réponse, malgré les éléments utiles également présents dans les autres réponses.

Comment: En définitive, je retiens la réponse d'Amphiteoh comme la plus complète dans son ensemble, mais il me semble que la variante la plus adaptée dans le sens logique ou philosophique est effectivement *proto-*. On ne peut malheureusement accepter deux réponses.

Answer (score 3):

Bien que le Robert ne donne pas de contraire pour *meta-*, *infra-* vient à l'esprit (alors que son contraire est *supra-*) comme réponse dans le contexte défini dans la question.

Le sens premier d'*infra-* est *en-dessous* (et non pas *en deçà de*), mais souvent on entend *meta-* comme *au-dessus de*, *infra-* devient, dans cet environnement le contraire acceptable de *meta-*

Il faudrait donner des exemples d'emploi de *meta-* pour savoir si *infra-* peut convenir comme contraire ou pas, ce qui sous entendrait qu'on pourrait remplacer *meta-* par *supra-* dans l'idée qu'on se fait du sujet à l'étude.

Comment: Même si ce n'est pas exactement satisfaisant, c'est effectivement une bonne piste, peut-être la meilleure pour le moment. Pour quel motif la réponse a-t-elle été désapprouvée (-1) ? Si c'est pour une raison constructive un commentaire aurait été utile.

Answer (score 3):

En terminologie, on parle de *méronyme* pour désigner un concept qui est une partie d'un concept plus large: pétiole est un méronyme de feuille. Le préfixe *méro-* a le sens de "partie, portion". Ce suffixe est toutefois généralement opposé à *holo-*.

Comment: De plus en plus intéressant ^^ Y a-t-il à ta connaissance un lien avec *métonymie* ?

Comment: @RomainVALERI Pas à ma connaissance. On parle carrément de champs d'application complètement différents (rhétorique vs. lexicologie), après tout. Au mieux, le méronyme correspond à la synecdoque, qui est une forme spécifique de métonymie.

Comment: J'ai toujours assez largement confondu métonymie et synecdoque, je vais aller réviser un peu mes définitions ;-)